# Finding a position in a word document to insert a table

Tags: c#, ms-word

I am working on writing some results of a database query into tables in Word. I have already done the code for accessing/creating objects from the results of my query and find myself a little stuck on writing these to a word template given to me. Its essentially a summary document in which i have to insert tables of the data i pulled from the db in the correct position in the document. So for instance, the document has say 4 section headers and under each header, there is some text after which i have to insert a table. One such header can be like:

**School Records**

Below you will find a table in which all school records will be listed:

So when i go to print my school record data object, i need a way to somehow insert my data in a table format right below the above line in the word document. Can anyone tell me how i can first find the correct position in the doc and then how you create a table in word from c#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [article about how to insert images at specific position](http://stephenchy520.blog.com/2012/02/23/cvb-net-insert-images-at-specific-locations-in-word-document/) in Word document. Maybe it's useful for you to insert table either.

Answer (score 0):

Add bookmark to the word template and then search for the bookmark and replace it with the image/file.