# How to add text into Word Documents at a specific position?

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

How do I write to a specific position in a Word document, for example, line 5, character 50? I have searched for a couple of hours, but couldn't find a solution.

I am using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are content with the more simple sentence, rather than lines:

```
ActiveDocument.Sentences(1).Characters(5).Select
Selection.Collapse
Selection.InsertBefore "added "
```

Five paragraphs and 50 spaces in VBA

```
Selection.Text = String(5, vbCrLf) 
Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
Selection.Text = String(50, " ")
```

However, for a particular position, I would prefer a textbox:

```
Set sh = doc.Shapes.AddTextbox(1, 10, 344, 575, 80)
sh.Name = "Course1"
```

With some properties:

```
sh.Fill.Visible = False
sh.Line.Visible = False
sh.TextFrame.MarginLeft = 0#
sh.TextFrame.MarginRight = 0#
sh.TextFrame.MarginTop = 0#
sh.TextFrame.MarginBottom = 0#
```

Comment: i want to add a text,a bookmark or something like that to an empty document,there aren't any Sentence!!should i add some paragraph first?i'm really confused about this!

Comment: If your blank document is active, you can just say `Selection.Text = "lots of text"`

Comment: yes,but there is no Sentences and no Characters in blank document!for example how to write in line 5 using this code?!

Comment: in the fact i want to know how to move cursor in a blank document to a specific position?i've tried everything so far!!

Answer (score 2):

If you will be inserting text at the same location every time a simple way to do this is to create a .dotx template file with a bookmark at the location.  Make sure the template is included in the build

```
Doc = Word.Documents.Add("Directory\Filename")
Doc.Bookmarks.Item("BookmarkName").Range.Text = "Text to be inserted"
```

Comment: This is a much better way of doing this

Answer (score 1):

[Finding a position in a word document to insert a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9603891/finding-a-position-in-a-word-document-to-insert-a-table)

You may find some useful information in the above location.

Comment: thanks,but i've read that already,but i didn't undrestand!!'i don't know where can i find some good information about Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word except msdn!