# Inserting RTF content in existing text range in Word using Interop assemblies

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, rtf

I'm working on generating the complex report from my WPF application in word format. Some of the content, I need to insert in the report is of RTF type. I'm not able to figure out the way to insert the RTF content at the end of particular text range.

As of now, I only know one way of adding the RTF content to word document programmatically and that is by setting the RTF content in clipboard and then paste the data back. But I'm not able to find the way to paste the content exactly after the existing content of text range.

I tried to add the paragraph at the end of text range and paste my RTF content to it but after looping through multiple paste operation final content I see in document is jumbled up and not in correct order.

[image]

Following is the code snippet I have tried :

```
        public partial class MainWindow : System.Windows.Window
{
    private List<TestData> TestDatas = new List<TestData>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        TestDatas.Add(new TestData() { Title = "Phrase 01", Description = @"Any RTF Text" });
        TestDatas.Add(new TestData() { Title = "Phrase 02", Description = @"Any RTF Text" });
        TestDatas.Add(new TestData() { Title = "Phrase 03", Description = @"Any RTF Text" });
        TestDatas.Add(new TestData() { Title = "Phrase 04", Description = @"Any RTF Text" });
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        var templateFilePath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"Report Template\"));
        Object oTemplatePath = templateFilePath + @"phrases.dotx";
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        Document wordDoc = new Document();

        wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add(ref oTemplatePath, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
        Selection sel = null;

        foreach (Field myMergeField in wordDoc.Fields)
        {
            myMergeField.Select();
            sel = wordApp.Selection;
            sel.Delete();

            Range initialRange = sel.Range;

            foreach (var data in TestDatas)
            {
                Range appendedRange;
                var textRange = AppendToRange(initialRange, data.Title + Environment.NewLine, out appendedRange, wordDoc);
                appendedRange.Bold = 1;
                appendedRange.Font.Size = 11;
                appendedRange.Underline = WdUnderline.wdUnderlineSingle;

                var para = textRange.Paragraphs.Add();
            }
        }

        wordDoc.SaveAs("myfile.doc");
        wordApp.Application.Quit();
    }

    private Range AppendToRange(Range range, string appendText, out Range appendedRange, Document wordDoc)
    {
        // Fetch indexes
        object oldStartPosition = range.Start;
        object oldEndPosition = range.End;
        object newEndPosition = (int)oldEndPosition + appendText.Length;

        // Append the text
        range.InsertAfter(appendText);

        // Define the range of the appended text
        appendedRange = wordDoc.Range(ref oldEndPosition, ref newEndPosition);

        // Return the range of the new combined range
        return wordDoc.Range(ref oldStartPosition, ref newEndPosition);
    }

}

public class TestData
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way to insert RTF content properly at particular location in text range?

Comment: Please provide the code you've tried that's not working... What's the RTF source, a file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12071425/how-to-add-text-into-word-documents-at-a-specific-position

Comment: @CindyMeister

I read RTF content from my database so my RTF text will be in text variable. 

Code which I have tried is something like this :

var para = textRange.Paragraphs.Add();                                        Clipboard.SetData(System.Windows.DataFormats.Rtf, text);
                                        para.Range.PasteSpecial(DataType: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdPasteDataType.wdPasteRTF);

Here "textrange" is the range in which I want to add RTF content and my RTF content is in "text" variable

Comment: @HansPassant

I prefer not to use shapes because it is a problematic later on while editing the document or doing overall alignment of document. Any other way you are aware of specifically for RTF content?

Comment: I thought since you have over 100 site rep points I wouldn't need to mention to use the [edit] link to add the code and additional information directly to your question... Please.

Comment: Please be more specific about what kinds of target ranges you want to use. "Jumbled up and not in the correct order" doesn't help us to reproduce what you require. You need to provide exact information about how to *identify* the target ranges.

Comment: @CindyMeister
I have added the code snippet and image of expected output vis actual output. Let me know if you can figure out the problem.

I want to add RTF text in loop. Any help?

Comment: I only just realized this was left unfinished. Have you managed to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try working with a `Range` object and "collapse" the Range as you go. I haven't tested the following, just off the top of my head...

```
var para = textRange.Paragraphs.Add();
var rng = para.Range;
Clipboard.SetData(System.Windows.DataFormats.Rtf, text);
rng.PasteSpecial(DataType: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdPasteDataType.wdPasteRTF);
rng.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);
//Alternative to insert a new paragraph
rng.Text = "\n";
//prepare for the next entry, for illustration - of course you'd built this into a loop
rng.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);
Clipboard.SetData(System.Windows.DataFormats.Rtf, otherText);
rng.PasteSpecial(DataType: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdPasteDataType.wdPasteRTF);
```

Comment: With the code snippet you have given above, I'm still facing the same problem i.e. rtf content is not appearing in the sequence in which I want it to be. 

My requirement is, I want to loop through the collection of object which has two string properties (i.e. title which is normal string and description which is rtf text) and print the title and description object wise. Any help?

Comment: @user2185592 Please edit your question, then and provide a [mcve] so that people can test exactly what you're using.

Comment: I have shared the sample code here. Pls check

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YpWLVjNpBboEqsE82jt3_9jRGJzK1qad

Comment: I'm not going to download something from an outside link @user2185592. Site policy is for you to provide everything required *in* the question.

Comment: I have added my code behind full code in question. Hope that helps.

Comment: I don't see that the code you've added even *attempts* to use what I suggested. And it's too bad you didn't have this, originally. In any case, working with the Start and End *values* is completely unreliable. Get rid of the entire AppendToRange function and just something like this in the loop: `initialRange.InsertAfter(data.Title + Environment.NewLine);`

Comment: initially I had used "InsertAfter" but it didn't work for me and resulted in jumbled text in final output (same like image pasted in question). Also, how I can provide different style to just title only if I use InsertAfter? appenededRange function returns the newly added content as range so I can apply the style on it.